# Change CSS style in Safari on all sites

Tags: macos, safari

I am looking for a Safari extension that allows me to change any CSS on any website.

The things I want to do is change the white background to black and the black text to white, I also want the links to be green.

Is there a extension that allows me to do this?

This is the OS X safari and not iOS.

I have looked at [this](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.canisbos.rightsizer-ZANVZTSER6) one but don't know how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don’t even need an extension; Safari has a built in setting in the advanced settings to use a custom CSS for all webpages:

[image: Safari settings]

You need to create your own CSS file, but that’s a completely different beast. Something that will work nice on some pages might not on others, but I’d create a file named whatever.css and have it contain something like this:

```
* {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background: #000000 !important;
}
a {
    color: #00ff00 !important;
}
```

and then load it into Safari via the preferences. To reload any changes to the CSS while Safari is open, you need to select `None Selected` and then re-select your custom file.

You’ll probably find lots of people on the web that have put lots of effort into similar CSS files. Good luck!

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, Can I make different CSS styles for different websites and pages using this method? Also is there a way how to change all elements apart from one? (Such as the toolbar on AD)

Comment: I don’t know. Unless there’s some way to do it using CSS syntax that I’m not aware of, I don’t think so. That would be the caveat. You could have several CSS files and switch between them for different pages, I guess…

Comment: I may change the style on every element and then change the other ones separately. How would I set the background of the toolbar on AD to white + the text black? I also want to be able to see the up/down vote and accept buttons.

Comment: I did not know you could use wildcard * {} cheers

Comment: [User CSS](http://code.grid.in.th/) will do per-website CSS. The extension is a little bit dated, but works for the version 8 and 9 of Safari.

Comment: Nice find! Also, some websites are starting to use HTML id tags on the html element. So styles can be applied to specific sites (e.g. facebook) using something like `html#facebook {…}` and `html#facebook child-elem {…}` for child elements. Though this will only work with those sites.

Comment: This is so helpful for me, thank you. On many older (or academic) web resources, everything is in Times New Roman (ugh) and the line spacing is so tight that it makes it hard to read.

Comment: Awesome! Nowadays you need something like Cascadea (https://cascadea.app/) to apply site-specific CSS for Safari (or Stylus, or Stylish, etc.).

Comment: It works! Note that I also had to use !important for the tweaks I wanted to make to kick in.