# How To Change the Color of My Browsers Background Safari

Tags: safari

I use Safari version 9.1.1.

I'm looking to make it easier to read my browser by changing the color of the background and text, however there is no option to do so that I can find in the settings panel.

Is this something I can change? Or would this require knowledge of coding?

Comment: Do you mean the background of websites? That is controlled by the developers who created the website.

Answer (score 1):

You can invert colors from System Preferences -> Accessibility. As mentioned in your comments, a webpage's background is in control of the developer/webmaster.

Answer (score 1):

If you are moderately versed in CSS, you can use the Safari extension [Quickstyle](http://canisbos.com/quickstyle) to select any page element and modify any of it's CSS attributes.

Once installed, click on the toolbar icon, hover over different elements on the page (they will be highlighted), and then click on the element you want to modify. A pop-up CSS editor will come up and you can edit to your hearts content. All changes are persistent, but non-permanent and you can edit or delete them as desired.

Note, I think the changes are stored in a cookie and will be wiped out if you clear cookies on Safari.

Changes can be made to the whole page or to specific elements site-wide.

I use it to increase the fonts for easier reading on a variety of sites, as well as to remove distracting elements.

Comment: If you're familiar with CSS, you don't even need the extension. Per this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176831/change-css-style-in-safari-on-all-sites you can define a user style sheet, which will override the site styling. Something as simple as body{background-color:#<hex color code here>} should work in 95% of the cases.